# How much are Gems worth?

Tags: hitogata-happa

In Hitogata Happa there's two kinds of gems; gems enemies drop when they die, Gems gained from bullets in the Zone of Control when an enemy dies. The normal gems are square cut and the ZoC gems from bullets are trilliant, triangle cut gems.

How many "gems" are each type worth? I'm wondering how many extra gems I get for having bullets in the ZoC, but being a Bullet Hell game it's hard to count how many gems each pickup is worth.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [instruction manual](http://www.gundemonium.com/hitogatahappa-manual.pdf) (page 6), large gems (the ones you get from enemies) are worth 4 small gems and can give you up to 1000 points.